# Describe the subgroup $K\leq S_4$ of order 8

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

How do I construct the subgroup $K$ (a subgroup of $S_4$ of order $8$) ?

Comment: The elements of order 3 do not form a subgroup of $S_4$.

Comment: The eight elements of order three do not form a subgroup of order $8$. On the other hand $S_4$ has order $24$ and does have subgroups of order $8$. I'm not sure whether it is the title or the body of the question you want answered.

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes.. I was wrong. I'm looking for the subgroup of order 8.

Comment: The question and the title describe very different problems.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I'm sorry... I fixed my question. Sorry I confused you all. My mistake.

Comment: There are no elements of order $8$ in $S_4$. Do you mean the number of subgroups of order $8$?

Comment: I'm trying to find the elements in the subgroup $K$ defined in the title. Is it correct now?

Comment: And $K$ is of order $8$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I fixed my question.

Comment: http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Symmetric_group_S4#Subgroups

Comment: There are three subgroups $K$ of order $8$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 such subgroups. Actually they are Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_4$ and all of them are isomorphic (moreover, conjugate in $S_4$). For example, take $K=\langle (12), (13)(24) \rangle$ (the group generated by permutations $(12)$ and $(13)(24)$).

More formally, $K \cong C_2 \wr C_2$ is the wreath square of $C_2$ (cyclic group of order $2$).

Comment: First of all, thank you for the detailed answer. I'm sorry to bother you with semantic but I don't understand the notation you wrote there where you defined $K=\langle (12), (13)(24) \rangle$. The syntax of permutations which I learnt in class looks like this : $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\4&3&2&1\end{pmatrix}$$ which defines the mapping from the permutation 1234 to the permutation 4321. Can you please explain what the permutations (12) and (13)(24) are in this syntax for example?

Comment: @SyndicatorBBB, here $(12)(34)$ is (the so called) representation as a product of independent cycles; that means $1 \to 2$, $2 \to 1$ and $3 \to 4$, $4 \to 3$. For example, the permutation in the comment above: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\4&3&2&1\end{pmatrix} = (14)(23),$$ or $$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&3&4&1\end{pmatrix} = (1234).$$